# Load application once it enters foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When i send my application to the background i need to kill the process, and when it comes back to foreground i need to load the application fresh. There is a setting in the Project or Targets where we can set it a property to TRUE. I am unable to find this property.

Can someone help me to figure this out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the key **Application does not run in background** ([UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5)) and set its value to **YES**.

[image]